# number convert into words onkeyup in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, onkeyup

I will try to convert Number into words using onkeyup event in CodeIgniter.

not necessary to read more description, I just add because StackOverflow does not add my question because of less description.

It's my view file

```
   <label for="name" class="field-wrapper required-field">Enter Amount of 
    Value:</label>
       <?php echo 

   form_input(['name'=>'price','id'=>'price','onkeyup'=>'myFunction()']); ?>
       <div class="col-lg-10">
      <?php echo form_error('price',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Conver Number to Words" name="convert"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
        <label class="control-label" for="readOnlyInput">In Words:<br><span 
     id="demo"></span> </label>

      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
```

now, the number convert into words function is in my Controller, How can I send a value of price & return into x?

It's my controller:

```
 public function pay_number($price)
  {
      $ones = array(
      1 => "one",
      2 => "two",
      3 => "three",
      4 => "four",
      5 => "five",
      6 => "Six",
      7 => "seven",
      8 => "eight",
      9 => "nine",
      10 => "ten",
      11 => "eleven",
      12 => "twelve",
      13 => "thirteen",
      14 => "fourteen",
      15 => "fifteen",
      16 => "sixteen",
      17 => "seventeen",
      18 => "eighteen",
      19 => "nineteen"
      );
      $tens = array(
      2 => "Twenty",
      3 => "Thirty",
      4 => "Forty",
      5 => "Fifty",
      6 => "Sixty",
      7 => "Seventy",
      8 => "Eighty",
      9 => "Ninety"
      );
      $hundreds = array(
      "hundred",
      "thousand",
      "million",
      "billion",
      "trillion",
      "quadrillion"
      ); //limit t quadrillion
        $price = number_format($price,2,".",",");
        $num_arr = explode(".",$price);
        $wholenum = $num_arr[0];
        $decnum = $num_arr[1];
        $whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",",$wholenum));
        krsort($whole_arr);
        $rettxt = "";
        foreach($whole_arr as $key => $i)
        {
          if($i < 20)
          {
          $rettxt .= $ones[$i];
          }
          elseif($i < 100)
          {
            $rettxt .= $tens[substr($i,0,1)];
            $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,1,1)];
          }
          else
          {
              $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i,0,1)]." ".$hundreds[0];
              $rettxt .= " ".$tens[substr($i,1,1)];
              $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,2,1)];
          }
            if($key > 0)
            {
              $rettxt .= " ".$hundreds[$key]." ";
            }
        }
          if($decnum > 0)
          {
            $rettxt .= " and ";
            if($decnum < 20)
            {
              $rettxt .= $ones[$decnum];
            }
            elseif($decnum < 100)
            {
              $rettxt .= $tens[substr($decnum,0,1)];
              $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($decnum,1,1)];
            }
        }
        echo $rettxt;
    }
```

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jquery load(..)` with that.

```
var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
$("#demo").load( "controller/pay_number/"+x );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use num2words JQuery plugin to archive your requirement. I have added plugin code directly you can name jquery.num2words.js as external file.

```js
$('#num').focus();
$('#demo').num2words();

$('#demo').num2words({
  units: [ "", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six","Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" ],
  teens: [ "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen","Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen", "Twenty" ],
  tens: [ "", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty","Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" ],
  othersIntl: [ "Thousand", "Million", "Billion", "Trillion" ]
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
Num2Words! jQuery Plugin (https://github.com/faizalmansor/num2words)
@author Faizal Mansor (osh@okijana.com) [http://okijana.com]
[Original base code & idea by Abhishek Sanoujam [http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/] (thanks!)]

Num2Words v0.1
Release Date: November 23, 2011

MIT License
Copyright (c) 2011 Faizal Mansor

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
(function($){
   $.fn.extend({ 
      num2words: function(options) {
  
   var defaults = {
      units: [ "", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six","Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" ],
      teens: [ "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen","Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen", "Twenty" ],
      tens: [ "", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty","Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" ],
      othersIntl: [ "Thousand", "Million", "Billion", "Trillion" ]
   };
    
   var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

   function NumberToWords() {
    var o = options;
    
    var units = o.units;
    var teens = o.teens;
    var tens = o.tens;
    var othersIntl = o.othersIntl;
    
    var getBelowHundred = function(n) {
     if (n >= 100) {
      return "greater than or equal to 100";
     };
     if (n <= 10) {
      return units[n];
     };
     if (n <= 20) {
      return teens[n - 10 - 1];
     };
     var unit = Math.floor(n % 10);
     n /= 10;
     var ten = Math.floor(n % 10);
     var tenWord = (ten > 0 ? (tens[ten] + " ") : '');
     var unitWord = (unit > 0 ? units[unit] : '');
     return tenWord + unitWord;
    };
    
    var getBelowThousand = function(n) {
     if (n >= 1000) {
      return "greater than or equal to 1000";
     };
     var word = getBelowHundred(Math.floor(n % 100));
     
     n = Math.floor(n / 100);
     var hun = Math.floor(n % 10);
     word = (hun > 0 ? (units[hun] + " Hundred ") : '') + word;
     
     return word;
    };
    
    return {
     numberToWords : function(n) {
      if (isNaN(n)) {
       return "Not a number";
      };
      
      var word = '';
      var val;
      var word2 = '';
      var val2;
      var b = n.split(".");
      n = b[0];
      d = b[1];
      d = String (d);
      d = d.substr(0,2);
      
      val = Math.floor(n % 1000);
      n = Math.floor(n / 1000);
      
      val2 = Math.floor(d % 1000);
      d = Math.floor(d / 1000);
      
      word = getBelowThousand(val);
      word2 = getBelowThousand(val2);
      
      othersArr = othersIntl;
      divisor = 1000;
      func = getBelowThousand;
   
      var i = 0;
      while (n > 0) {
       if (i == othersArr.length - 1) {
        word = this.numberToWords(n) + " " + othersArr[i] + " " + word;
        break;
       };
       val = Math.floor(n % divisor);
       n = Math.floor(n / divisor);
       if (val != 0) {
        word = func(val) + " " + othersArr[i] + " " + word;
       };
       i++;
      };
      
      var i = 0;
      while (d > 0) {
       if (i == othersArr.length - 1) {
        word2 = this.numberToWords(d) + " " + othersArr[i] + " " + word2;
        break;
       };
       val2 = Math.floor(d % divisor);
       d = Math.floor(d / divisor);
       if (val2 != 0) {
        word2 = func(val2) + " " + othersArr[i] + " " + word2;
       };
       i++;
      };
      if (word!='') word = word.toUpperCase() + ' DOLLARS';
      if (word2!='') word2 = ' AND ' + word2.toUpperCase() + ' CENTS';
      return word+word2;

     }
    }
   }

   return this.each(function(){
    
    var obj = $(this);
    var input = $("input[type='text']", obj);
    var button = $("input[type='button']", obj);
    var div = $("div", obj);
    
    input.change(function(){
     div.hide();
     var inputval = input.val();
     if (isNaN(inputval)){
      div.html("This is not a number - " + inputval);
      div.show("slow");
      return;
     };
     var num2words = new NumberToWords();
     var intl = num2words.numberToWords(inputval);
     
     div.html(intl);
     div.show("slow");
    });
    button.trigger('change');
    input.focus();
    
   });
      }
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>


<div id="demo">
  Enter amount: $ <input id="num" type="text">
  <input id="trans" type="button" value="Convert to words">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is link for [Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Numbers-Into-Words-num2words.html). Hope this helpful to you.

Regards.

Comment: Its very helpful for me,Thank you very much

Comment: Have fun.. close question if this is what you want

Comment: sorry, I am new here, but how can I close the question but not deleting.